# How to extract date time from a column in KQL?

Tags: kql

I am trying to extract the Date time from a column ProtectionStatusDetails.

Below is the snip for this

[snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTR3G.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parse` operator, e.g:

`... | parse ProtectionStatusDetails with "AntivirusSignatureLastUpdated: " ts:datetime`

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator